# Do memory limit set on pod affect how linux kernel decide when to reclaim cache memory?

Tags: kubernetes, linux-kernel, containers, kubernetes-pod

We're running a pod in k8s, and not until recently we added a memory monitor dashboard for it. After a while we found the following trend:

1. `container_memory_rss` stayed very stable (the third line from the top)
2. the `container_memory_working_set_bytes` (along with `container_memory_cache`) seemed to keep growing

You can see the growing trend from the **left** part of the graph.

Trying to figure out why, I added the **memory limit** in the k8s pod, and then restart the pod, and suddenly the lines become much more stable. (You can see this from the **right** part of the graph.)

**Now go back to my question:**

- Why did the cache memory keep growing without being reclaimed when pod memory limit is not set? Was that due to too much free physical memory on node? (around 64GB)
- Does setting memory limit on pod affect how frequently Linux reclaim the `container_memory_cache` memory?
- Is there any official document on this?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: The left side diagram has 5 days worth of data while the other is only 2. Also, it depends on the # of workload at the point of scraping as well. There's a good chance with the same amount of data you will see identical trend.

Comment: @gohm'c thanks for the response! From your answer, are you suggesting k8s memory limit won't affect how Linux kernel works?

Comment: nothing concrete found from official documents. Are you able to reproduce your case? I found this article useful: https://faun.pub/how-much-is-too-much-the-linux-oomkiller-and-used-memory-d32186f29c9d